# Can't connect to my router 192.168.1.1?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I recently changed ISPs to a better one, and the first thing I did was to log into the router page which usually has a standard address of 192.168.1.1, I saw that there was no connection so I went to terminal and typed `ping 192.168.1.1` there was no answer so I went to my ISP's official website, logged in, and changed the LAN configuration from `192.168.0.1` to `192.168.1.1` it then rebooted my modem automatically, after it was done I went to cmd to ping again and it worked, but when I tried in the URL it did not work still, it says `192.168.1.1 refused to connect.` although I don't have any firewall blocking it.

Comment: So within your OS use ipconfig and provide us the output

Comment: The IP address of the router is the same as the default gateway on your PC. Check if it is correct. How are you trying to connect (SSH or web)?

Comment: The default gateway is 192.168.1.1, and I'm trying to connect through web

Comment: Did your new ISP provider you with a router?  In a lot of cases (in the UK certainly), you get a new one which is pre-configured for easy access.

Comment: If you can reconfig your router by accessing the ISP's web site, then it sounds like they have a pretty tight hold on your router from their end. They may simply not allow local access. Alternatively, try ethernet not WiFi. It's quite possible [& very sensible] to not allow config over wifi.

Comment: @Stephen Yes I'm pretty sure they provided me with a router along with my modem.

Comment: @Tetsujin I did, I tried both ends, nothing still.

Comment: Then I'd say, ask your ISP.

Comment: I guess that's the final solution. @Tetsujin thanks.

Comment: Is there a make and model of your router?

Answer (score 1):

Are you are sure you are connected to the router you think you are? I had the same problem once when my PC's wifi was connected to a different router. In that case it won't work whatever you try, so check that first.

If you want to connect to your router you need to know two things, the IP address and a port number the router is listening at. The IP address is (as said before) the same as the gateway address of your PC. The port number can be anything. HTTP normally uses port 80 but it can be almost anything. Port 81 or 8080 are common for HTTP too. HTTPS normally uses port 443 but can also configured different like 10000 or 20000. You can use a portscanner to check what ports are open or you can try brute force like this:

```
http://192.168.1.1:80/
http://192.168.1.1:81/
http://192.168.1.1:8080/
```

or

```
https://192.168.1.1:443/
https://192.168.1.1:10000/
https://192.168.1.1:20000/
```

etc.